# C#: Querying a remote server to see which user has a lock on a file

Tags: c#, active-directory, wmi

** EDIT: The original question was not clear. I can't FIND IADsFileServiceOperations in any .Net assembly, and that's the problem - not that I don't know how to use it **

I've been digging around for hours and can't figure this out...

In C#, is there a way to query a remote file server (preferably using a `ManagementObjectSearcher` but not nessecarily) and ask it which user currently has a lock on a file?

The best I could come up with is

```
var en = new DirectoryEntry($@"\\{hostName}\root\cimv2");
var fso = sessQuery.NativeObject as IADsFileServiceOperations;
var resources = fso.Resources();
```

but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to use `IADsFileServiceOperations` in a .Net project.

Help...? Please...?

Comment: Could that help you? https://books.google.co.il/books?id=v88wVsLHcDAC&pg=PT472&lpg=PT472&dq=IADsFileServiceOperations&source=bl&ots=sVRKRqdFRy&sig=ACfU3U05l6q586PgSz_RtPpjIOJgqgwBEw&hl=iw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG9p6VhrniAhXKMewKHRuyCzwQ6AEwCnoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=IADsFileServiceOperations&f=false

Comment: Thanks @Roni but apparently my question was badly phrased. What I meant was that I can't find IADsFileServiceOperations in any .Net assembly and don't know how to link to it so that it is usable in a .Net application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IADsFileServiceOperations` is an interface that exposes two methods:

1. IADsFileServiceOperations::**Resources**
2. IADsFileServiceOperations::**Sessions**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsfileserviceoperations#methods

> The IADsFileServiceOperations::Resources method gets a pointer to a
>   pointer to the IADsCollection interface on a collection of the
>   resource objects representing the current open resources on this file
>   service.

```
var en = new DirectoryEntry($@"\\{hostName}\root\cimv2");
var fso = sessQuery.NativeObject as IADsFileServiceOperations;
var resources = fso.Resources(); // returns resource objects representing the current open resources on the file

foreach(var res in resources)
{
   // res.User
   // res.Path
   // res.LockCount
   if(res.LockCount > 0)
   {
      // user has lock on file
   }
}
```

**Update 1:**

To add active directory types to your `.NET` project, you need to add a COM reference to the project. Go to the add reference dialog, then `COM` tab and add `Active DS Type Library`.

By adding this `COM` reference you have all `AD` types, interfaces by using `ActiveDS`.

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Ali, but my question apparently wasn't clear. My problem is not that I don't know how to use IADsFileServiceOperations, but that I don't know how to BE ABLE TO use it in .NET - that is, I cannot find it in any .Net assembly...

Comment: @user884248 sorry for the misunderstanding. I updated the answer and it solves your problem.

Comment: Ali - you are the best. Thank you!